# MVVM Проброска свойств из Model во View

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

Работаю с проектом где необходимо создать много VM для Model. В итоге получается много копи пасты. Для каждой VM я копирую все свойства из Model. И возник вопрос:
Можно ли "пробросить" свойства из Model во View?

Comment: Можете копировать, можете оборачивать, можете использовать напрямую (не забывая про утечки памяти). Тут сколько вариантов - столько и мнений

Comment: vitidev, а что Вы имели ввиду когда писали про оборачивать и использовать на прямую? Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать по этим темам.

Comment: `View` не должен вообще ничего знать про другие слои, он должен лишь привязываться к абстракции, неким именам, которые могут быть, а которые и не могут быть в VM слое. А вот сам VM, берет и инициализирует Model слой, забирая из него нужные данные, формируя на их основе свойства для привязок.